# Proving that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a Noetherian ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noetherian

So by definition I know that for all increasing chain of ideals: $I_1\subseteq I_2\subseteq \ldots I_k\subseteq I_{k+1}\subseteq \ldots$
in $\mathbb{Z}$, $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}, n \geq 1: I_n = I_{n+m} \forall m\in \mathbb{N}, m\geq 1.$ Or at least that was the definition I was given. But I am a little lost in how to work with Ideals, let a lone this sort of sequence of ideals. I thought of working with $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with p prime. But didn't get far.
Can anyone guide me through this? explain everything. That would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you know about ideals of $ \mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 2):

You can show that any PID is Noetherian (hint: suppose an infinite sequence of ideals exists, and take their union $I$ and verify it's an ideal in a PID $I = (a)$, and find $I_n$ where $a \in I_n$ since $a \in I$).

To show that $\mathbb{Z}$ is noetherian, just note that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID.

Comment: More generally, any ring where all ideals are finitely generated is Noetherian, by the same argument. In fact, the converse also holds (although the converse requires countable choice and excluded middle to prove). A Noetherian ring is thus precisely a ring where all ideals are finitely generated.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
There's a lot of ways to go about approaching this. You can show for yourself (the very useful fact) that if $R$ is a commutative ring then following are equivalent

1. Every ideal in $R$ is finitely generated.
2. Every ascending sequence of ideals stabilizes.
3. Every non-empty collection of ideals of $R$ has a maximal element with respect to containment.

As Anas mentioned if $R$ is a PID then obviously any ideal is finitely generated and by this equivalence is therefore Noetherian.

If you want to work directly with ideals of $\Z$, just remember that ideals of $\Z$ are exactly $n\Z$ for some $n \in \Z$. Therefore any strictly ascending chain of ideals has the form
$$
(n_1)\subsetneq (n_2) \subsetneq \dots
$$
But any such chain must terminate. The reason is that if there are only finitely many ideals of $\Z$ which contain $(n_1)$ by the correspondence isomorphism theorem. Precisely there is a bijection between the ideals of $\Z$ containing $(n_2)$ and ideals of $\Z/(n_2)$, which is a finite ring.